# Python parse panda zmq stream

Tags: python, parsing, zeromq

I am trying to parse a zmq stream in a client application. The stream looks like this:

```
{"tick": {"instrument":"EUR_GBP","time":"2016-02-17T16:53:45.616062Z","bid":0.77791,"ask":0.77807}}
```

I tried this:

```
def parse_tick_data(self, line):
        dt_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
        time = datetime.strptime(dict_data["time"], dt_format)
        ask = float(dict_data["ask"])
        bid = float(dict_data["bid"])
        instrument = dict_data["instrument"]
        return time, instrument, bid, ask

time, symbol, bid, ask = self.parse_tick_data(line["tick"]) 
print(bid,ask)
```

But get the following error:

```
time, symbol, bid, ask = self.parse_tick_data(line["tick"]) 
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Formatting code/errors to improve readability

Answer (score 0):

In your code `line` variable type is `String`, you can't access string indices over string like you did in `line["tick"]`.
You can access integer indices over string and that will return the character at the given index.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I understood the error, but i don´t understand how i could change the response fron the rest api/zmq?

Comment: You will need to share the code of your request and response if you want help on that part as well.